# Axiom of extensionality: Implies vs If... Then statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

What is the reasoning for labeling the axiom of extensionality as an implies operator rather than an if... then statement? For example, I have seen the axiom of extensionality written as an if...then statement and not an implies operator as described in the [*Axiom of extensionality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) Wikipedia page.

Also, I understand that an if... then statement that is a tautology is the same thing as an implies operator. I think I am missing something simple, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you say yourself, if ... then and implies is the same. So what is your question?

Comment: Not clear... if it is about the [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#List_of_common_logical_connectives), it is only the choice to use $\Rightarrow$ instead of $\to$ or $\supset$. Unfortuantely, there is no stable international "standard".

Comment: "if... then statement that is a tautology" ? Of course the *Axiom of Extensionality* is **not** a tautology

Comment: The axiom states a condition on two sets that licenses us to conclude with their equality: **if** the sets $A$ and $B$ have the same elements, **then** they are *equal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If $A$ then $B$" means *the same thing as* "$A$ implies $B$". The use of one rather than the other is just a choice of language - they both mean the same thing, "$A\implies B$".

Meanwhile, I don't understand what tautologies have to do with this, but as Mauro commented the axiom of extensionality is not a tautology. For instance, consider the $\{\in\}$-structure whose domain is $\{a, b\}$, and whose $\in$-relation is empty. This *fails* the axiom of extensionality - $a$ and $b$ have the same elements (namely, none) but $a\not=b$. So extensionality is not a tautology, since it is not true in every structure.

Comment: Implies is slightly different then if A then B regarding the two definitions, but I see what you mean by it not being a tautology.

Comment: @Will "Implies is slightly different then if A then B regarding the two definitions" No, it's really not - "$A$ implies $B$" and "if $A$, then $B$" mean exactly the same thing. What difference do you think there is?

Comment: @NoahSchweber - maybe the reason for the misunderstanding is the "eternal querrel" between "implication" as [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) (the connective) and "implication" as [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) (i.e. *entailment*)  :-)

Comment: Exactly see page 8 on this link  http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/2406_2012/basic_logic.pdf. How do you tell the difference between these two?

Comment: Rather, in this context it is used as a conditional correct?